# Define a C API with callbacks

Tags: c, function

I'm a Java/C++ programmer trying to write a portable C API. It's a big state-machine with lots of states, and I need a way for the user to provide functionality for each individual state.

In Java or C++, I would define an Interface or Pure Virtual class with all the parse functionality, like so:

```
class StateHandler {
public:
  virtual void handleState1(const StateData &data) = 0;
  virtual void handleState2(const StateData &data) = 0;
  // ...
}

class StateMachine {
public:
  StateMachine(StateHandler &handler) : _handler(handler) {}
  void transition(const StateInput &input);
private:
  StateHandler &_handler;
}

StateMachine::transition(const StateInput &input) {
  StateData state_data;
  // ... stuff ...
  _handler.handleState1(state_data);
}
```

I'm wondering what's the best way to do this in C? Two ideas come to mind... the first is essentially a copy of the "class" approach above, but using structs and function pointers:

```
struct state_handler_t {
  void (*handleState1)(void *user_data, state_data_t *state_data);
  void (*handleState2)(void *user_data, state_data_t *state_data);
  // ...
};

struct state_machine_t {
  // opaque details of state machine
  // ...

  // pointer to user-provided data
  void* user_data;
};

state_machine_t *new_state_machine(void* user_data) {
  // ...
}
transition(state_machine_t *state_machine, state_handler_t *callback) {
  state_data_t state_data;
  // ... stuff ...
  callback->handleState1(state_machine->user_data, &state_data);
}
```

This feels like I'm trying to program in the languages I know (using OOP) rather than embracing the language I'm using.

The other alternative I considered is to forward declare all the handler functions, and let the caller link in their implementations:

```
void handleState1(void *user_data, state_data_t *state_data);
void handleState2(void *user_data, state_data_t *state_data);
// ...

// state_machine_t same as above

transition(state_machine_t *state_machine) {
  state_data_t state_data;
  // ... stuff ...
  handleState1(state_machine->user_data, &state_data);
}
```

The issue I have with this one is that I'm preventing users from defining more than one handler implementation.

Any pointers (pardon the pun) or words of wisdom from you C gurus?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to abandon OOP design concepts just because you're using `C`.  It's a common to provide a struct full of function pointers to define an interface.

Comment: While I agree with @cleblanc I would strongly recommend using an actual OOP language if at all possible. Static analyzers tend to not handle function pointers very well, and in a system large enough to be useful I think this merits at least reconsidering the implementation language

Comment: The [X Toolkit library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Toolkit_Intrinsics) uses object oriented concepts rather heavily. When I was using it, I was quite impressed with how they did it. You might want to take a peek at it.

Comment: The second alternative is IMO the cleanest solution (i.e. least amount of code), however it requires the integrating developer to be above average in terms of compiler skills; renaming in case of naming collisions, handling multiple definitions etc. In the end it is hardly "portable" if few knows how to integrate it (although technically possible)

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez, I plan to provide both a C++ OOP API, and a functional C API. The plan is currently to write the core code in C, and add a C++ wrapper. It seemed less heavy than the other way around, though I don't have any real experience doing this